# Problem with compiling C++ program

Tags: compiling

I'm using linux live image. I'm facing problem with compilation as if I compile it by using g++, " bash: g++: command not found...". What to do know ! Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [/bin/bash: g++: command not found error 127](http://askubuntu.com/questions/583171/bin-bash-g-command-not-found-error-127)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have g++ installed? Use the commands bellow to install g++, if you don't have it already:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++
```

And this question is kind of duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348654/how-to-install-g-compiler) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/583171/bin-bash-g-command-not-found-error-127) one.